# Use of getActiveNetworkInfo() as an alternative to deprecated ConnectivityManager.getBackgroundDataSetting() does not honor it

Tags: android, background-process, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, connectivity

Use of `getActiveNetworkInfo()` as an alternative to deprecated `ConnectivityManager.getBackgroundDataSetting()`  for Android 4.0 and above does not honor the background data setting when changed(restricted). Is there any other alternative ?

**Here's the code snippet:**

```
 ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
 connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if(connectivityManager != null) { 
        NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info.isConnected() == true) {
            System.out.println("running");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Background settings enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            System.out.println("active network info null"); 
            System.out.println("enable background services");
            Toast.makeText(context, "background settings disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        LogUtil.w(getClass(), "Application does not have ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE Permission");
    }
```

Note:"`if(connectivityManager.getBackgroundDataSetting()`" works for 2.3.3 but when replaced with "`if (info.isConnected() == true)`" for android 4.0+ always returns true even when background data settings are restricted.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.x only returns that you aren't connected when the check is made when the app is not in the foreground.  See if you can arrange to make this check in a Service while some other app is in the foreground.